# Get previous observations in a data frame in R

Tags: r

I want to add a new column to a data frame that contains the i*th*-1 value. I can do this in a for loop but I would like to know it there is a more straightforward way to do it. I would also like to do it for other lags. 
Example:

```
Price PrevPrice
23 NA
24 23
25 24
35 25
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either do

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df, PrevPrice=lag(Price))
```

Or

```
df$PrevPrice <- c(NA, df$Price[-nrow(df)])
```

If you have multiple columns to get the `lag`, another option is `data.table` where you can use `?shift` By default, the `type` is `lag`.  For multiple columns, specify the column index (for example, 1st 2 columns here) in `.SDcols`.

```
library(data.table) #data.table_1.9.5
setDT(df)[, paste0(names(df)[1:2], 'lag') := shift(.SD), .SDcols=1:2]
```